# How to Analyze the amount of battery being used by my Android App

Tags: java, android, performance, service, battery

I have developed an Android App.

But sometimes I can notice that my app is consuming battery even when I am not even opening it once.

The Battery consumption is more than 1 % and goes up to 5 % at times.

My App has four Broadcast receivers-

1)Evey time the device is booted my App gets a receiver

2)Every Time my Application is updated my App gets a receiver

3)When Ever the user changes the device time or date again my App gets a receiver

4)An Alaram Reciever

My app sets an Alaram with the user's consent which is triggered every day at a particular time and performs a small function present inside an Intent Service which might last for a maximum of 1 Minute.

I believe that the battery consumption is not because of these receivers/services as these were the part of the app from starting but the battery consumption has risen in recent times. Could there be a chance that some library/SDK is consuming battery?

Is there any tool which could help me analyze the reason for the consumption of the battery by my app?

**EDIT - I am not sure why this question has been marked duplicate but the other question doesn't address the full problem. I want to exactly track down which library or class is consuming battery. Whereas the other question only mentions the way to track down the battery usage by the app.**

Comment: heavy background operation is cause battery consumption. this is the major issue.

Comment: @HemantParmar Thanks for your Answer. As mentioned earlier that all these receivers/services were there before but the rise in battery consumption has risen in recent times. I have not changed a single line of code related to these receivers/services. Could there be any library which could be consuming battery? If yes how should I figure out which one is the culprit?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "library or class consuming the battery". The hardware is what consumes the battery. Your job is to examine which of the things that your code instructs it to do contribute the most. The duplicate covers this.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Thanks for the clarification. The App suggested in the duplicate seems to be no more available. Can the Android Studio 3.0 version help me with this?

Comment: The answer with the outdated link is not the only answer. The app may have been renamed and/or moved; google for it and optionally suggest an edit to update the link.